# Compiling C++11 with g++ 5.4

Tags: c++, c++11

`-std=c++11` seems to be ignored when compiling :

```
    g++ -std=c++11 -I../include -I ../../../Toolbox/CShmRingBuf/ -I$MILDIR/include CFrameProd.cpp -o CFrameProd.o
CFrameProd.cpp: In constructor ‘CFrameProd::CFrameProd()’:
CFrameProd.cpp:33:24: error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
     MilGrabBufferList_ = {0};
```

I tried `-std=c++0x, -std=gnu++0x, -std=c++14`, nothing helped.

Here is my g++ version :

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: what is the type of `MilGrabBufferList_ `?

Comment: Hi Davide, it's a long integer array  : long MilGrabBufferList_[10]

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/GriHvs)

Comment: @P.W [Can Reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364199/4834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below reproduces the original error:

```
class CFrameProd{
    public:
    CFrameProd(){
        MilGrabBufferList_ = {0};
    }
    private:
    long MilGrabBufferList_[10];
};

4:28: error: assigning to an array from an initializer list

         MilGrabBufferList_ = {0};
```

However, this code compiles without error:

```
class CFrameProd{
    public:
    CFrameProd(){}
    private:
    long MilGrabBufferList_[10]={0};
};
```

Class member initialisation is used here.

The original error occurred because you cannot assign to an array after its declaration.

(there is always the option of using an initialiser list: `CFrameProd(): MilGrabBufferList_{0}{}`)

Comment: Many thanks for your help Quamrana, this is the exact situation I'am experiencing : class member initialization failure. I've been misled by the compiler error message evoking the -std option need... Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be assigning the initializer list to the array address after array declaration like this:

```
int main()
{
    long int foo[5];
    foo = {0};
}
```

which produces the error: `assigning to an array from an initializer list`

Instead it should like this:

```
int main()
{
    long int foo[5] = {0};
}
```

In your case it would be: `long MilGrabBufferList_[10] = {0};`

Comment: Many thanks for your help, this is the actual issue. I've been misled by the compiler error message evoking the -std option need... Thanks again !

Comment: @sylwa37 The `-std` option is not mentioned at all in the error message you showed us.

Comment: @sylwa37: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: True ! I did clip it off unintentionally : g++  -g -std=gnu++11  -W -Wall -I../include  -I../../../Toolbox/CShmRingBuf/ -I/opt/matrox_imaging/mil/include -Woverloaded-virtual -ansi -pipe -fno-for-scope -DGNU_GCC  -DDEBUG   -c -o ../src/CFrameProd.o ../src/CFrameProd.cpp
../src/CFrameProd.cpp: In constructor ‘CFrameProd::CFrameProd()’:
../src/CFrameProd.cpp:38:24: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
 MilGrabBufferList_ = {0};

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to an array, in any version of C++.

Your problem is not compiler flags, but your code.

Comment: Obligatory: present a [MCVE] when you write a question like this, so that we can see what's _really_ going on.